# scanf não para em um laço

Tags: c

```
int main(){
char texto[1000];
do{ 
    scanf("%[^\n]", texto);
    if(!fakeEquals(texto)){
        if(palindromo(texto)){
            printf("SIM\n");
        }else{
            printf("NAO\n");
        }
    }
}while(!fakeEquals(texto));

return 0;
```

É um programa que retorna se uma String é palindromo ou não, quando estava usado scan("%s", texto); estava funcionando, mas como preciso ler espaços também, mudei para scanf("%[^\n]", texto); só que quando digito qualquer palavra fica me retornando SIM ou NAO infinitamente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar um espaço no `scanf(" %[^\n]", texto);` porque é preciso limpar o buffer antes de ler outra vez, porque senão ele lê uma vez e depois nunca mais lê a outra palavra

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo :)

Comment: Ótimo, se resolveu o problema vote na resposta, é importante votar quando resolve o nosso problema [votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: @VictorHarry Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 